# Amazon Elastic File Storage(EFS) not automatically adding capacity

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have created an EFS volume and mounted it to a Linux EC2, and in turn mounted the EFS volume using samba for use on a Windows EC2.

When my drive reached near about 150gb, it did not grow automatically to accommodate new files.

[This guide](https://erudinsky.com/2017/08/30/aws-efs-windows) is basically what I did to create my drive mount.

It doesn't seem to me that it being Windows (which is officially not supported for EFS) should prevent it from growing as files are added to it over the network.

Comment: Every EFS filesystem (not "volume") reports a free space of 8 exabytes (`8.0E`) back to the OS.  No growing is required, as the capacity is logically infinite from initial creation.  Check `df -h` on the Linux side.  It sounds like Samba is exposing an EBS volume, not an EFS filesystem.